# how to share multiple files with ShareCompat

Tags: android, android-intent

My question is how to share multiple files with `ShareCompat intentBuilder` in android.

My code throws exception:

> android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle
>   Intent { act=android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE flg=0x80001
>   pkg=com.google.android.gm (has clip) (has extras) }

My code is:

```
 static void with(Activity activity, ArrayList<String> imageFile,String app){
    ArrayList<Uri> imagesUri=new ArrayList<>();
    for (String i:imageFile)
        imagesUri.add(FileProvider.getUriForFile(
                activity, FILES_AUTHORITY, new File(i)));

    Intent shareIntent = ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from(activity).getIntent();

    shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
    shareIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,imagesUri);
    shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

    activity.startActivity(shareIntent);

}
```

Is throws error for every app (package name).

Answer (score 2):

the following works for me:

```
ShareCompat.IntentBuilder shareIntent = ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from(activity).setType("image/*");
    for(String address : addresses ) {
        File file = new File(address);
        Uri imageUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
                activity,
                "app.signature.fileprovider",
                file);
        shareIntent.addStream(imageUri);
    }
    Intent intent=shareIntent.getIntent();
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose Application"));
```

you should use addStream() to add multiple files.

Answer (score 1):

After a very hard time searching on sites like stackoverflow. I found a solution in @Ian Lake's blog post that works for me and makes sense too.

```
 ShareCompat.IntentBuilder shareIntent = ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from((Activity) context)
                .setType("video/image/*");
        String[] files = parentDirectory.list();
        if (files != null) {
            for (String address : files) {
                File file = new File(address);
                File filePath = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(null), "vids");  //vids is a directory local to my app in i.e storage/0/emulated/Android/data/com.myapp.videoeditor/vids
                File newFile = new File(filePath, file.getName());
                if (address.contains("cut_video")) {
                    Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
                            context,
                            "com.myapp.videoeditor.fileprovider",
                            newFile);
                    shareIntent.addStream(uri);
                }
            }
        }
        Intent intent = shareIntent.getIntent();
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose..."));
```

res/xml/file_paths.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-files-path name="external_files" path="vids/"/>
</paths>
```

Manifest

```
<application
....
....>
 <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.myapp.videoeditor.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <!-- ressource file to create -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths">
            </meta-data>
...
...
</application>
```

Comment: not working ???

Answer (score -1):

Did you add intent filter in AndroidManifest.xml for the activity that is supposed to receive the files?

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
</intent-filter>
```